# How to implement vpn program in uwp ？

Tags: windows, uwp, vpn

I want to implement agent software like iOS under uwp，Such as shadowrocket.
Implement various protocols through the system's VPN interface.
I am a student without software engineering experience, so I want to know some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to implement agent software like iOS under uwp，Such as shadowrocket. Implement various protocols through the system's VPN interface

If you want to create a VPN client App in UWP, you need to implement [IVpnPlugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.vpn.ivpnplugin) Interface. Read through the doc and you will get some basic ideas of implementing the VPN Client.

Notes: IVpnPlugin belongs to [Windows.Networking.Vpn namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.vpn), which requires networkingVpnProvider [restricted capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capabilities).